# how to pass all request query parameters to embedded controllers in twig symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

```
{{ render(controller("SomeBundle:Foo:Bar", {HERE I WANT TO PASS ALL query parameters app.request.query.all}) }}
```

So can I access all master request query parameters in sub request and the subrequest should also run independently?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
{{ render(controller("SomeBundle:Foo:bar", {'all': app.request.query.all}) }}
```

and in action store it in `$all` variable

```
public function barAction($all) {
    // other your code
}
```

Comment: in that case how SomeBundle:Foo:bar url will work if I want to access it directly and not through subrequest. I want to make sure it works in both cases.

Comment: Try to dump `$all` and `subrequest`, and you see they are different. Also it's depend of your specific goals. I think you probably need to use `$all` exactly

Answer (score 4):

From your controller:

```
array_merge($request->query->all(), $request->get('_route_params'));

//query->all : get all query string parameters
//_route_params : get current route parameters
```

From your twig template must be sth like:

```
app.request.query.all|merge(app.request.attributes.get('_route_params'))
```

I've never used this in twig templates, so first test it ;)

Then you can use that functions however you want to build the variables you'll pass to your subrequest

Answer (score 2):

To just pass in what is in app.request.query.all:

```
{{ render(controller("SomeBundle:Foo:Bar", app.request.query.all)
```

To merge something extra in:

```
{{ render(controller("SomeBundle:Foo:Bar", { something: 'extra' }|merge(app.request.query.all))
```

Tested in Symfony 3.3.10 and Twig 1.35.0