# symfony 3 form does not work with twig render(controller('...'))

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

I want to build a navigation-bar, that's displayed on every page.
Therefore I added the following code to the `base.html.twig`

```
{{ render(controller(
    'AppBundle:Navigation:index'
)) }}
```

However `$form->isSubmitted()` returns `false` and `$form->getData()` returns `null`. This is only the case for the twig-render way above. If I open the Navigation:index page normally through the `/navigation`-route, `$form->isSubmitted()` returns `true` and `$form->getData()` returns the form-data.

Here is the NavigationController:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use AppBundle\Entity\Language;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use AppBundle\Form\Type\NavigationType;
class NavigationController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/navigation", name="navigation")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $language = null;
        $form = $this->createForm(NavigationType::class);

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        dump($language);
        dump($form);
        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
        {
            dump('is valid');
        }
        $data = $form->getData();
        dump($data);
        dump('isSubmitted(): ' . $form->isSubmitted());
        dump($form->isSubmitted());

        // replace this example code with whatever you need
        return $this->render('navigation/index.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```

Does anyone have a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you embed a controller, Symfony does it via an internal sub-request, that's why isSubmitted is false, and getData returns null.

A workaround is to pass the original request, as you found.

A better option is to use the request stack (available via the `request_stack` service IIRC) and its `getMasterRequest` method.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I found a workaround now. One needs to make the `$request`-object available manually

The way to do this is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21672058/1273555).

Just change the twig-code to:

```
{{ render(controller("SomeBundle:Foo:bar", {'request': app.request) }}
```

and in the action-function add the $request variable

```
public function barAction($request) {
    // other your code
}
```

Now the form-code should work.

Comment: I have a similar problem. I can render in twig  using the controller or a route name but my knp pagination call used at the destination controller thinks the route is that of the controller that is rendering the template which then calls render as above.